# Android Realm - findAll returns objects with null parameters

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I need to do a simple query in Realm, retrieve a list of MyModel object and later use it somewhere else in my app. It happens that once I query Realm, each object has null values, but the *toString* returns the expected values.

Model:

```
@RealmClass
public class MyModel extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

public static final String KEY_MODEL = "key_myModel";

@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private String myStr;
private int myInt;

//.... getters and setters

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "id = " + id
            + "\nmyStr = " + myStr
            + "\nmyInt = " + myInt;
}

}
```

How do I store the value:

```
public static void storeModel(MyModel model) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(model);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

How do I retrieve the objects:

```
public static RealmList<MyModel> getNewElementsFromIndex(int indexFrom) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<MyModel> allValues = realm.where(MyModel).greaterThan("id", indexFrom).findAll();

        RealmList<MyModel> finalList = new RealmList<MyModel>();
        finalList.addAll(allValues.subList(0, allValues.size()));
        return finalList;
    }
```

When i call *getNewElementsFromIndex(value)* i get a list of item, but all items in this list have the parameter *myStr = null* and *myInt = 0*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just return `allValues`?

Comment: For no specific reason...I still have the same result -> Null parameters inside the object.

Comment: 1.) you should use the RealmResults, 2.) you aren't closing the Realm instance you open with `getInstance()`, 3.) what you describe is documented and expected behavior.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce if i close Realm instance and then do .isEmpty() on the returned list I get the error: "This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable."

Comment: That's because this isn't where you should be opening it in the first place. It's in the best practices section of the docs:  https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For managed realm objects, data is not copied to the fields, you obtain them through the proxy getter/setter calls.

Therefore, the fact that fields are null and toString() shows the values is completely expected and well-documented behavior.

To see the values, you have to add watches for the getter methods.

See the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#testing-and-debugging).