# Android Realm inserts object, but fields are null

Tags: android, null, insert, realm

I try to insert object to Realm database, object is inserted, but it's fields become "null".

Here is all the code. At line "person.setAge(14);" I can see, when put a breakpoint, that person.Name is already null, but I have just set a value!

Code of activity:

```
  package wovilonapps.realmtraining;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import io.realm.Realm;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         realm = Realm.getInstance(this);

        realm.beginTransaction();

        Person person = realm.createObject(Person.class);
        person.setName("Young Person");
        person.setAge(14);
        realm.commitTransaction();

        ArrayList<Person> result =  new ArrayList(realm.where(Person.class).findAll());
        Log.d("MyLOG", "ds");
    }
}
```

Code of class Person:

```
    package wovilonapps.realmtraining;

import io.realm.RealmObject; 

public class Person extends RealmObject {
    private String Name;
    private int Age;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will probably solve your problem -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144934/android-realm-findall-returns-objects-with-null-parameters

Comment: Thank you for links, but I can't understand, what should I cahnge in my code to fix the problem? In duplicate question is told about fields of Realm Objects, but what to change? P.S. I traced setter work through Proxy class up to Row setting, it works normally...

Comment: I made a small sample app running your code and there were 2 problems: 
1. You didn't initialize the realm instance. As explained in this example (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) you must call 'Realm.init(context)' once in your application otherwise your application will crash.
2. The method 'Realm.getInstance(context)' isn't existing. Use 'Realm.getDefaultInstance()' or pass a RealmConfiguration if you want to use 'Realm.getInstance'

Comment: I understood the problem!!! Program has no mistakes, code is correct, but one must know, that Realm works not with object directly, but with it's proxy "copy". That's why, if one looks at object in breakpoint, he can see null fields, so that values are somewhere in Realm. But if you use query to get object, it will be OK, with non null fields. So, try query up to the end and object will be normal.