# Picasso does not load image url reference, but loads "http://...."

Tags: android, picasso

Picasso doesnt load images if I use imageURL reference but loads when I use actual url e.g. "http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/161017171526-cafe-neo-cup-super-169.jpg"

```
    String imageURL = feedItem.getImageUrl();
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageURL).resize(600, 0).into(newsImage);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Image url is: "+imageURL);
```

Here is the log output from above

```
10-20 22:32:00.141 13274-13274/bw.co.fus.print I/NewsFeedAdapter: Image url is: "http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/161017171526-cafe-neo-cup-super-169.jpg"
```

Picasso loads when I use this

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/161017171526-cafe-neo-cup-super-169.jpg").resize(600, 0).into(newsImage);
```

I have tried different resize options, including .fit() and without, also .centercrop(). Also thought it could be null but clearly its not.

Comment: do you get actual url in reference ?

Comment: feeditem.getimageurl ??

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: One more thing could you share your adapter code ?

Comment: problem was because of quotation marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check if your feedItem#imageUrl variable doesn't have quotation marks on either side. According to your log output, it has. If you are passing URI to Picasso as a String, it should look like

> http://whatever.com/...

and not

> "http://whatever.com/..."

Also, use debugger to find out more about what's inside of your model for this specific time (beware, if you are using Realm, it will shown as null, here's [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32218724/6942800))